# Yearweek and yearmonth to date in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following date formats:

```
Yearweek  Yearmonth
  202053     202012
```

How could I turn them into dates? For example, `202053` will become `2020-12-28` (that's the first day of this week), and `202012` will become `2020-12-01`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A format string for ISO year and ISO week is `%G` and `%V` respectively, so below query is expected to work but fails with no reason (seems to me at least)

```sql
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%G%V', '202053')
```

> Failed to parse input string "202053"

To workaround this, you can modify a *Yearweek* string like below,

```sql
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%G-%V' '2020-53') AS yearweek_dt
```

[image]

*Yearmonth* has no issue, so putting two things together:

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT '202053' Yearweek, '202012' Yearmonth
)
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%G-%V', LEFT(Yearweek, 4) || '-' || RIGHT(Yearweek, 2)) AS yearweek_dt,
       PARSE_DATE('%Y%m', Yearmonth) yearmonth_dt
  FROM sample_data;
```

you will get following result:

[image]